# PHP error when trying to login with email that is not in database

Tags: php

I have a code below

```
//When user clicks on login button
 if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])){
   $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);


   if(empty($email)){
     $errors['email'] = "Email field is required";
   }
   if(empty($password)){
     $errors['password'] = "Password field is required";
   }


   if(count($errors) == 0){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
      $_SESSION['isLoggedin'] = true;
      $_SESSION['name'] = $user['name'];
      $_SESSION['birthday'] = $user['birthday'];
      $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
      $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
      $_SESSION['verified'] = $user['verified'];
      header('location: index.php');
      exit();
    }
    else
    {
      $errors['wrongcred'] = "Wrong email/password combination";
    }
   }


}
```

I have declared $errors array for email and password.  $errors['email'] = "Email field is required" - If email field is left empty,   $errors['password'] = "Password field is required" - If password field is left empty, $errors['wrongcred'] = "Wrong email/password combination" - If user enters wrong credentials. When I enter email address that exists in database but wrong password its works as intended - shows that user entered wrong email/password combination. The problem is that when I enter email address that not exists in database, php gives me this "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null", I want it to display as $errors array that user entered wrong email/password combination.

Comment: You need to check if `fetch_assoc()` returns no data, it will be null if there are no more rows.

Comment: Usually you do a count(*) to see if any rows returned. If > 0 then select to get data.

Comment: @MTMDev That's pretty much pointless (and subject to race conditions). You do know just fine when a select query does not return rows.

Comment: @Álvaro-gonzález I have some PHP websites running fine for over 10 years. I guess I did it wrong. :p

Comment: @MTMDev why would you perform 2 queries when the return value of `fetch_assoc()` can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
```

into this:

```
if(isset($user['password']) && password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
```

Explanation: when there is no such e-mail address, the SQL query returns no data (empty set). Therefore $user['password'] is not set at all (not existing). You try to pass this to the password_verify function and you get this notice.

In my proposed code, the if statement will evaluate false if the variable is not set and there will be no notice because the rules are parsed from left to right and there's && (logical AND - when the first one is false it knows that the whole will be false and it will never evaluate the second condition).

Comment: Btw - if email is not a unique key (or not checked upon acct create that it already exists), then that has the potential for two people to use the same email and therefore lock out one of the two people. Just fyi,